# Adding two variables which contain the values from two different tables of same database

Tags: php, sql

Can we add two select sql queries from two different tables of same database and of same data type.These two queries are selecting unique cell from the table after satisfying the where condition. Now i want to sum up these two queries which are of same data type(i.e float type). How to perform addition operation:
For Ex: $sql=1 and $sqlNew=2... i want $add=$sql+$sqlNew=3

```
$sql = "SELECT num1 FROM tech WHERE name1='dsf'"; //Selecting a particular cell from table tech
$sqlNew = "SELECT num2 FROM technew WHERE name2='asd'"; //Selecting a particular cell from table technew
$add = $sql + $sqlNew; // Can this operation be perfromed?
```

Want to add cells from two different tables and want to save it in a new variable.
    Please let me know how to performe above operation. I am new to sql.
    this is my complete code:

```
    <html>
<body>

<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "sample";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$add="SELECT (tech.num1 + technew.num2) as total FROM tech, technew WHERE tech.name1 = 'def' AND technew.name2 = 'asd'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $add); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
echo $row['total']; 
$sql4 = "INSERT INTO finaladdition (id, finalAddTotal ) VALUES (NULL,'$row[total]')";
$conn->close();
?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are name1 and name2 unique in those tables? If not, each of those queries could return multiple rows and your question will need more explanation as to how that should be handled. If so, it should be easy enough.

Comment: Remove the single quotes around `$row['total']` in the INSERT query. That is a number which needs no quotes.

Comment: @JayBlanchard thank you a lot for giving your valuable input...Now this code is running fine with no error and i am able to store the value in database...Thank you for sharing your knowledge...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just do a JOIN (in the example the INNER JOIN is implied) query:

```
SELECT (a.num1 + b.num2) as total
FROM tech a, technew b
WHERE a.name1 = 'def'
AND b.name2 = 'asd'
```

Based on further information this is what you should do:

```
$add="SELECT (tech.num1 + technew.num2) as total FROM tech, technew WHERE tech.name1 = 'def' AND technew.name2 = 'asd'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $add); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
echo $row['total']; 

$sql4 = "INSERT INTO finaladdition (id, finalAddTotal ) VALUES (NULL,$row['total')";
```

Comment: The method is right but I'd like to state that this is most certainly not a join query. It's just adding 2 values.

Comment: @Niels the implied join is `FROM tech a, technew b` which constitutes and INNER join.

Comment: Ah yes indeed, my bad

Comment: Because `$add` is the database result from which you must fetch the value. For example:  `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($add); echo $row['total'];`

Comment: Did you do `mysqi_query($connection, $query);`? Do you know how to do queries with MySQLi?

Comment: Then `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res); echo $row['total'];` assuming you used the query exactly as I have written it.

Comment: Before you said your connection was `$link` now you're saying `$conn`. Which is it? And if it is `$conn` the error checking must use that, not `$con` You also said `$res` before, `$result`. Pick a set of variable names and stick with them.

Comment: You cannot insert before the variable is set.

Comment: @JayBlanchard...Still its shownig error...Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\Apache24\htdocs\SLCSA\learning php\add.php on line 22...still nothing is getting echo...and and not able to insert its showing syntax error...i will upload my code again....please check it